# Convert IEnumerable<dynamic> to string[]

Tags: c#, massive

I have the code below, basically returns a single column of string values from a DB using MassiveORM.

The Query() method returns IEnumerable. I'm trying to find out how to cast or convert that to a simple string array.

Using the below I get

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.String[]

Thanks

```
var response = new MakesResponse();
var tbl = new DynamicModel("SONICAPI");
string sql = "EXEC pGetMakes";
var result = tbl.Query(sql);

return new MakesResponse()
{
makes = (string[])result.ToArray(),
ExecutionTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
Result = "200",
ResultText = "OK",
Source = "DB"
};
```

Comment: Do you know how to cast a single result to a string?

Answer (score 10):

You can cast the enumerable items. This will only work if they are really `string`:

```
makes = result.Cast<string>().ToArray()
```

Else, you can call `ToString`, if there is a good implementation of it:

```
makes = result.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray()
```

Comment: Hi, makes = result.Cast<string>().ToArray() gives me Unable to cast object of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to type 'System.String'

Comment: @Ben Maybe your result containes types other than string as well, some nulls for example

Comment: So maybe it doesn't contain a `string`, as you say, but rather an object of type `ExpandObject`.

Comment: @Ben Try `result.Cast<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>().Select(e => (string)((IDictionary<string, object>)e).FirstOrDefault().Value).ToArray()`.

Comment: Patrick, that gives me a collection of key/value pairs. The key is always "make" which is the db column name, the values are the string values i'm trying to access.

Comment: I updated the code just after I posted it. Can you retry please?

Comment: @Ben Need more help?

Comment: If you have no further questions, please accept the answer you deemed most helpful by checking the check mark before that answer.